# Tensorflow object-detection package error when change batch size

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection, object-detection-api

I am trying the newly released object-detection API for tensorflow.
I used the sample training program in the tutorial, i.e, fine-tuning the FRCNN-Resnet model on the pet dataset. Using only one GPU, an error message always show up when I change the batch size to a value more than 1 (default is 1). The error message looks like this:

InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): ConcatOp : Dimensions of inputs should match: shape[0] = [1,750,600,3] vs. shape[1] = [1,600,804,3]

Answer (score 1):

You are likely using the `keep_aspect_ratio_resizer` which allows each image to be a different size, which means that you can only train with batch size 1.  To train with larger batch sizes, the only way to currently handle this in the API is to use the `fixed_shape_resizer`.  See some of the SSD configs for examples of this.